# Take input values and pass it into javascript function for Chart.js chart in ASP.NET core Razor Pages

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, chart.js, razor-pages

[Current look of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQS0n.png)

I am trying to pass the values from my 2 inputs into my clickupdate() js function to set a new range for the chart shown. The numbers represent the indexes of the list that is going to be shown. So basically from which index to which index the chart is supposed to be rendered.

```
@page
@model statmath_web.Pages.Visualization.VisualizationMainModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CSV Data Visualization";
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<center>

    <td >
        <input class="text-center param-input" id="Minimum_Parameter_Value"
        type="number" min="0" max="@Model.length" step="1"
        placeholder="Min" value="0" /> 
    </td>

    <td>
            <input class="text-center param-input" id="Maximum_Parameter_Value"
        type="number" min="0" max="@Model.length" step="1"
                   placeholder="Max" value="@Model.length"/>
    </td>

    <br />

    <button onclick="clickupdate()">Update Data</button>

    <canvas id="myChart" width="1200" height="700"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.TimeList.GetRange(0, 50))),
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "VSE Value",
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                    borderColor: "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
                    fill: false,
                    data: @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.ValueList.GetRange(0, 50))),
                }
            ]
        },
      options: {
        animation: false,
        parsing: false,
        responsive: true,
      },
    });
    
    function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels = label
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data = data;
    });
    chart.update();
}

    function clickupdate(){
        labelsNew = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.TimeList.GetRange(Number(Minimum_Parameter_Value) , Number(Maximum_Parameter_Value) - Number(Minimum_Parameter_Value))))
        dataNew = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.ValueList.GetRange(Number(Minimum_Parameter_Value) , Number(Maximum_Parameter_Value) - Number(Minimum_Parameter_Value))))
        addData(myChart, labelsNew, dataNew);
    }

</script>

</center>
</body>

</html>
```

So far I tried to set constants, vars in the js part but these throw "'name' does not exist in current context" (CS0103).

I realize that I can pass these as jQuery strings into my URL but for this task there should be a much cleaner way. Maybe the mixup of Razor and Javascript is the big issue.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to create new variable lists in Javascript part and then used .slice() on them.

See updated code:

```
@page
@model statmath_web.Pages.Visualization.VisualizationMainModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CSV Data Visualization";
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<center>

    <td >
        <input class="text-center param-input" id="Minimum_Parameter"
        type="number" min="0" max="@Model.length" step="1"
        placeholder="Min" value="0" /> 
    </td>

    <td>
        <input class="text-center param-input" id="Maximum_Parameter"
        type="number" min="0" max="@Model.length" step="1"
        placeholder="Max" value="@Model.length"/>
    </td>

    <br />

    <button onclick="clickupdate()">Update Data</button>

    <canvas id="myChart" width="1200" height="700"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

    var TimestampList = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.TimeList));
    var ValueList = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.ValueList));

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: TimestampList,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "VSE Value",
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                    borderColor: "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
                    fill: false,
                    data: ValueList,
                }
            ]
        },
      options: {
        animation: false,
        parsing: false,
        responsive: true,
      },
    });


    function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels = label
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data = data;
    });
    chart.update();
}

    function clickupdate(){
        var pMin = document.getElementById('Minimum_Parameter').value;
        var pMax = document.getElementById('Maximum_Parameter').value;
        labelsNew = TimestampList.slice(pMin, pMax);
        dataNew = ValueList.slice(pMin, pMax);
        addData(myChart, labelsNew, dataNew);
    }

</script>

</center>
</body>

</html>
```